# Antd Design [Table] how to expand row by click in the column

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an expandable table with the last Action column for Submit or ViewDetails (expand more information )

[image: Antd Expaned Table]

Idk how to make the expand function in column.render(),
Currently, I do the trick with expandRowByClick: true.

```js
<Table
  expandable={{
    expandedRowRender,
    rowExpandable: (record) => record.key % 2,
    // expandIconColumnIndex:7
    expandRowByClick: true,
    expandIcon: () => <div />
    }}
  dataSource={data}
/>
```

But it's not the answer, cuz there's some column that rendered with a link, other onClick callback, or the text `More detail` should be changed by the state of expanding (More/Less).

Antd design version 4.16.0

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/antdnestedtables-zrtuw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the row expands on a row click is because of `expandRowByClick: true`. Remove it.
Now, if you want to render that hidable row on your custom button, then you need to manually set `expandedRowKeys` prop on `Table` component. You can read up on that more AntD documentation here: https://ant.design/components/table/#API

Now in your case its simple.

1st. Create somewhere to store your expended keys, that has to be done with the use of a state like so `const [expended, setExpended] = useState()`

2nd. Create a method that adds and removes the expended key on a click. NOTE it has to be do both as when you click the `expend` button, it send same `index` to same method. So you have to check if its already selected or not.

```
const expend = (index) => {
    if (expended === index) setExpended(undefined);
    else setExpended(index);
};
```

Here is an example that only 1 can be expanded at once. If any more is expanded - others will close down and that one will open. If you want to allow users to expand multiple at once - need to redo this to work with an array instead.

Pass this newly created method to your `a` element with `onClick={() => expend(index)}`. NOTE only do it whenever its a `More details` button.

3rd. Render it in a table like so

```
<Table
  className="components-table-demo-nested"
  columns={columns}
  expandable={{
    expandedRowRender,
    rowExpandable: (record) => record.key % 2,
    expandIcon: () => <></>
  }}
  expandedRowKeys={[expended]}
  dataSource={data}
/>
```

The `expandedRowRender` remains as in your case. `expandIcon` is set to an empty fragment and its Important as without it it will render the default AntD Icon on the left. The `expandedRowKeys` is the keys of the expended rows. It has to be an array hence why `expended` is in `[]` since, as mentioned, this example made so only 1 row at the time can be expanded.

Result: It only expands whenever you click your custom `More Details` button in `Actions` column. In addition, made it so if the row is expanded, instead of `More details` it would say `Close details`

Here is a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/antdnestedtables-forked-orq20?file=/index.tsx